# Changing the space between next and back buttons

Tags: html, css, wordpress, pagination, themes

I'm using The Point theme and I'm trying to move the previous page button to appear to the left side, I looked at the Styles.css file and figured how to make the next page in the right side but I can't figure out how to expand the space between the two buttons and make the previous page button in the left side, they are just stacked together...

Here is a screenshot of it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF7WC.jpg

and here is the pagination code from the styles.css file :

```css
/* Pagination */
nav.posts-navigation { clear: both }
.pagination {
 clear: both;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 5px auto;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 18px;
}
.single .pagination {
 border: 0;
 box-shadow: none;
 -moz-box-shadow: none;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 margin-top: 0;
 padding: 3% 0;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: right;
}
.pagination ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 display: inline-block;
}
.pagination ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.pagination .current, .pagination .dots, .pagination a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0 1px 0 0;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 1;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 10px 13px;
 background: #2a2a2a;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.single .pagination .current {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: transparent;
}
.single .pagination a .currenttext {
 padding: 0;
 background: transparent;
 color: #FFF;
 margin-right: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.single .pagination a:hover .currenttext { color: #fff }
.pagination a {
 background: #38B7EE;
 margin: 0 1px 0 0;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 1;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 10px 13px;
 transition: all 0.25s linear;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.pagination ul li:last-child a { margin-right: 0 }
.pagination a:hover { color: #fff }
.pagination i.icon-left { margin-right: 7px }
.pagination i.icon-right { margin-right: 7px }
.top {
 float: right;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: -18px;
 width: 52px;
 height: 52px;
 margin-left: -26px;
 background: #eee;
 border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
 border-radius: 30px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
 -moz-border-radius: 30px;
 z-index: 100;
}
.pnavigation2 {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 15px 0;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.pagination .nav-previous { float: left }
.pagination .nav-next { float: right }
.pagination .nav-previous a, .pagination .nav-next a { color: #fff!important }
.pagination .nav-previous a:hover, .pagination .nav-next a:hover { background-color: #222 }
.single .currenttext { margin-bottom: 0 }
.pagination .current .currenttext { margin-bottom: 10px }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use Flexbox and `justify-content: space-between`. Each link button (flex children), becomes pinned to either corner of the parent element.

```css
.pagination {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #35bbee;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination">
  <a class="btn btn-prev" href="#">Previous Page</a>
  <a class="btn btn-next" href="#">Next Pages</a>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ujh8xogd/1/)

Comment: Oh Thank you, so Should I add this code to the rest of the pagination code?

Comment: @Ahmedalghadi Without seeing how your `HTML` is structured, it's difficult to say. This was a proof of concept to show you how to add it to your own code. Just remember that for Flexbox to work, only immediate flex children are affected. If you have a lot of nesting in your `HTML`, things won't work as expected.

Comment: Hey again, thank you very much for your answer about this, I tried looking and fixing this but couldnt.. I am lost and i would like to get your help if you do not mind..

Comment: @Ahmedalghadi Sure, I'd like to help. Can you open a new question and we can begin there? Make sure to include a runnable code snippet that people can test. Be as specific as you can.

Comment: thank you for responding mate, I have looked at what the theme uses and it is HTML5 and CSS3, what should I put as a runnable code snippet in the new question to make thing easy and fast?

Comment: @Ahmedalghadi The answer found in the following link shows exactly how you should form your stack snippet. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do